# How to show just a div in iFrame using jQuery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Hi I would like to load a page using iFrame on my website. and as a final result I need to hide everything  and show just one div's inner text. How can I accomplish it using jQuery?
or maybe another workaround

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have

Iframe contains div with `id='someID'`:

```
<div id="someID">Hello world!</div>
```

Use the following to access the HTML

```
$('#iframeID').contents().find('#someID').style('display:none;');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<b>$("#test").contents().find("#content").setAttribute("style","display:none");</b>
```

Sorry I believe this is better suited to what your looking to do.